# How to add noise to the first index in nump array

Tags: python, numpy

How to add noise to the first index of array,with the number of iterations the max number iteration is 2.

I want to add a noise in range (1, max_iterator) to rows in order, for example:

- add 0.788 to row 1st
- add 1.233 to row 2nd
- add 0.788 to row 3rd
- add 1.233 to row 4th
- and 0.788 to row 5th
- and so on

I've tried to use this code but it doesn't work

```
a = np.array([[858,833,123],
             [323,542,927],
             [938,361,271],
             [679,272,451]])
noise = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=0.1, size=1)
max_iter = 2
for i in range(max_iter):
    for j in range(len(a)):
        a[i][0] = np.clip(a[i][0] + noise, a_min=0.0, a_max=None)
print(a)
```

Comment: What does this code produce, and why is it not what you want?

Comment: `add noise in range (1, max_iterator)`  and `add 0.788` contradicts itself isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```py
# you'll need to cast the array as floats rather ints to add other floats
a = np.array([[858,833,123],
             [323,542,927],
             [938,361,271],
             [679,272,451]]).astype(float)

n = 2

# create n random values
noise = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=0.1, size=n)

# loop through rows in steps of n
for i in range(0, a.shape[0], n):
    a[i:i + n, 0] = np.clip(a[i:i + 1, 0] + noise, a_min=0.0, a_max=None)
```

Comment: how to make n dynamic. because in real case I will use n=50

Comment: as this - add 0.788 to row 1st
- and 1.782 to row 50th
- and 0.788  to row 51th
- and so on

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the issue is? Having `n=2` is just an example based on your question, but if your array `a` was big enough then changing the value of `n` to 50 should also work.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell from your code or question if this is what you want or not:

```
a = np.array([[858,833,123],
             [323,542,927],
             [938,361,271],
             [679,272,451]])
a[:, 0] += np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=0.1, size=len(a))
a[:, 0] = np.clip(a[:, 0], a_min=0.0, a_max=None)
```

This adds noise to the first column